# Подключение jQuery после скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

Если подключать jquery до вывода формы все работает:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form_3" enctype="" action="/feedback">            
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function ShowResponse_form_3(responseText){
                $('#form_3_container').html(responseText);
                               }

           $(function(){
               $('#form_3').ajaxForm({
                   type     : 'post',
                   dataType : 'html',
                   data     : {
                       action   : "checkFormData",
                       isAjax   : true,
                       ajaxSend : "1"
                   },
                   beforeSend  : showAjaxLoading,
                   complete    : hideAjaxLoading,
                   success     : ShowResponse_form_3});
           });
        </script>
        тут содержимое формы 
</form>
```

Если подключать jquery после вывода формы ничего не работает:

```
<form method="post" id="form_3" enctype="" action="/feedback">            
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function ShowResponse_form_3(responseText){
                $('#form_3_container').html(responseText);
                               }

           $(function(){
               $('#form_3').ajaxForm({
                   type     : 'post',
                   dataType : 'html',
                   data     : {
                       action   : "checkFormData",
                       isAjax   : true,
                       ajaxSend : "1"
                   },
                   beforeSend  : showAjaxLoading,
                   complete    : hideAjaxLoading,
                   success     : ShowResponse_form_3});
           });
        </script>
        тут содержимое формы 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Как подключить jQuery после формы чтоб все работало?

Answer (score 1):

нужно просто вынести скриптовую часть после подключения jquery , а сами формы пусть остаются на месте.

Сделайте себе свой js файлик аля common.js и туда весь js пишите, так и код чище будет и все будет на своих местах

Comment: Формы генерируются динамически вместе с этим скрпитом через php, так что вынести их в отдельный файл очень геморно

Comment: тогда увы иначе никак ,  $() работает только с jquery , если эта функция не видит jquery , работать не будет , подключайте сверху страницы , раз это cms какая то , что поделать , раньше все скрипты подключали сверху и жили как то :)